# How to access the `customLabel` in a `customTableViewCell` at UITests?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode-ui-testing

There are many rows. I want to access particular label. 
Then based on that label text, perform either Tap or ignore.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about your question.?

Comment: yes, There is a tableview with many rows, that rows have label. I want to get label.text value.

Comment: Please show us some code. Normally if you are trying to get that label text on clicking a cell then you should look into `didSelectRowAt indexPath` delegate method of tableview.

Comment: Tuhin, this is automation UITest, we are not manually tapping. and we don't write delegate method in tableview.

Comment: Okay, Understood. In this case you can try to print the description of testable object(i.e. tableview) and confirm which object is in the hierarchy and accessible.  After that you can get access to your customLabel.

Answer (score 2):

Set an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the label inside the cell, then find that label using the identifier in your test. You can then inspect its text using the [`label` property of `XCUIElement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1500692-label) and decide whether to tap it or not.

```
// app code
let label = UILabel!
label.accessibilityIdentifier = "myLabel"

// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let labels = app.staticTexts.matching(identifier: "myLabel")
for i in 0..<labels.count {
    let label = labels.element(boundBy: i)
    if label.label == "interesting text" {
        label.tap()
    }
}
```

You could also use an [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500471-matching?changes=latest_minor) to narrow down the query before you loop through and tap each element.

```
// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label MATCHES 'interesting text'")
let labels = app
    .staticTexts
    .matching(identifier: "myLabel")
    .matching(predicate)
for i in 0..<labels.count {
    labels.element(boundBy: i).tap()
}
```